# How to get the content using DOM

Tags: jquery, dom

I use the HTML DOM to get the content:

```
$contener = $html->find('div.classname', 0);
```

This works if I have only one classname or multiple classnames with different name. However, if I have 2 classnames with the same classname (in 2 parts), HTML DOM gets only the first classname and ignores the 2nd part.

How can I get all content with this classname (appear 2 times in the content).

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the arrow function, you can use the following way.

```js
var $container = $("html").find("div.test");

alert($container.length);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="test">1</div>
<div class="test">2</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Kaustubh Khare, I have tried several times and see that the source url is partially encrypted by JS and the encrypted part could not be retrieved by html dom